# Get subdirectories with specific prefix

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cycle, prefix, subdirectory

I'm creating simple batch script for deleting all user configs of specific application and I'm still failing on the last step where I'm trying to get all subfolders with specific prefix...

This is what I have right now:

```
@echo off
chcp 1250

SET appUserConfigDirectory=\AppData\Local\CompanyName
SET appConfigFolderPrefix=AppName.exe_Url

:: get parent folder of user folders
for %%d in (%USERPROFILE%) do SET userprofilesFolder=%%~dpd

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: going through all user folders
for /F "delims=" %%d in ('dir %userprofilesFolder% /A:D-R-H-S /b') do (
    :: set full name of CompanyName folder in user AppData
    SET appConfigParentFolder=%userprofilesFolder%%%d%appUserConfigDirectory%
    IF EXIST !appConfigParentFolder! (
        :: There is a problem with dir command, it's says File not found even if subfolder with this prefix exists and print all subFolder no metter it's name...
        for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir !appConfigParentFolder! /A:D /b %appConfigFolderPrefix%*') do (
        echo %%i)))
```

Comment: You must do it in Batch scripting? PowerShall ok?

Comment: Yes, I have version with powershell, but for some reasons I need to do it in batch.

Comment: What should the script do, what is the error you are facing? Please [edit] your question and clarify! Consider to read [mcve]. Hint: **never** use the `::`-style comments in code blocks; always use `rem` instead...

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont know how to describe the problem  better than I did. I already had my answer. But thank you for hint with comments. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the way how to do it. The right dir command with prefix should be:

```
dir !appConfigParentFolder!\%appConfigFolderPrefix%* /A:D /b
```

So the full version of this sample is:

```
@echo off
chcp 1250

SET appUserConfigDirectory=\AppData\Local\CompanyName
SET appConfigFolderPrefix=AppName.exe_Url

for %%d in (%USERPROFILE%) do SET userprofilesFolder=%%~dpd

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /F "delims=" %%d in ('dir %userprofilesFolder% /A:D-R-H-S /b') do (
    SET appConfigParentFolder=%userprofilesFolder%%%d%appUserConfigDirectory%
    IF EXIST !appConfigParentFolder! (
        for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir !appConfigParentFolder!\%appConfigFolderPrefix%* /A:D /b') do echo %%i
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with something like this:

```
forfiles /S /M !appConfigParentFolder! /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rmdir @path"
```

It removes every subdirectory, which equals `!appConfigParentFolder!`.

Comment: Thank you for answer @Dominique. :) The appConfigParentFolder is a folder that can contain config folders of many apps => this is why I'm searching by prefix. So I need to remove only appConfigParentFolder subfolders which starts with appConfigFolderPrefix. In my answer below, I finally got all this subdirectories and now I can simply remove them.

Comment: Again, no need to use `FORFILES` in this instance.  Using the standard `FOR` command with the appropriate options would suffice. As I have told you in the past `FORFILES` has a lot of overhead because is will open a new `cmd.exe` instance for every file or folder it is processing.